# Dropzone js using new function dropzone renameFIle

Tags: javascript, html, web, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js for my website and try to rename Files before uploading.
Recently dropzone added the new function renameFile, which I can't get to work.
Is this a bug or do I understand the function wrong ?

console.log() is not called.

```
Dropzone.myDropzone = false;
var size = 1;

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
maxFilesize: size,
renameFile: function(file){
    console.log("I was called");
    return "newname.pdf";
},
paramName: "pdffile",
url: "UploadServlet",
acceptedFiles: "application/pdf",
dictDefaultMessage: "Ziehe Dateien hierhin zum Hochladen",
dictFallbackMessage: "Dieser Browser wird leider nicht unterstützt",
dictFileTooBig: "Die Datei ist leider zu groß. Erlaubtes Maximum sind " +size +" MB",
dictInvalidFileType: "Dies ist leider der falsche Dateityp. Es werden nur PDF-Dateien unterstützt",
sending: function (file,xhr,formData){

    formData.append("dateiname",file.name);
}

}
```

Comment: i think you have to set the new name like `file.upload.filename = "newname.pdf"`

Answer (score 2):

Here's my code I just got working. Currently the documentation is in no way correct. file.upload.filename just throws errors constantly. It says the old methods are depreciated as well.

my whole block:

```
<form id="my-dropzone" action="upload.php" class="dropzone"></form>
<script src="/sci/dropzone.js"></script>
<script>
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    chunkSize: 5000000,
    retryChunks: true,
    retryChunksLimit: 2,
    chunking: true,
    timeout: 60000,
    maxFilesize: 1000,
    dictDefaultMessage: "Click or Drag/Drop files here to upload",
    renameFile: function(file) {
        return file.name = "NAME-PREFIX_" + file.name;
    },
    init: function() {
        this.on("uploadprogress", function(file, progress) {
            console.log("File progress", progress);
        });
        this.on("success", function(file) {
            console.log(file["name"]);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Notice I put a prefix. In my code I add the days date (through PHP since it doesn't rely on the client having correct time)

```
    renameFile: function(file) {
        return file.name = "NAME-PREFIX_" + file.name;
    },
```

Say your file is "me.jpg" you'll get "NAME-PREFIX_me.jpg"